# More effecient way of changing PHP results displayed

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script that displays a bunch of database results in a nice grid and paginates them.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a way to change the number of results displayed per page using a drop down system so I started to play with AJAX.

I have a variable that determines the amount of items to be displayed so what I've done is I've created a few more pages that have the exact same PHP code, but with a different number for that variable. It does what its intended to do, but I can't help but feel I've gone about doing this in the most inefficient way imaginable because I had to create three additional pages with the differing variable.

How can this be improved?

This is the php code. I used to have it in the page itself but have move it to another file which the ajax looks at.

```
<?php


                //Add the file that connects to the database
                include("C://wamp/www/site/config.php");    
                //Selects which database to get the data from
                mysql_select_db("products");

                //Variables for pagination 

                $per_page = 24;                 
                // get the number of items that actually have Oven in their name
                $sql = "SELECT SUM(rowcount)
                        FROM (
                        SELECT COUNT(1) AS rowcount 
                        FROM brand1
                        WHERE description LIKE '%oven%' 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT COUNT(1) 
                        FROM brand2
                        WHERE description LIKE '%oven%'
                        ) AS counts";
                $pages_query = mysql_query ($sql) ;
                //Ceil rounds up to the nearest number so that we don't get pages with decimals on the end
                $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

                //append a page=1,2,3 at the end of the URL to indicate which page the user is on

                //set : 1 so that if a person doesn't pick a page it automatically sets them on page 1.
                $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

                $start = ($page -1) * $per_page;

                //Selects which table to extract the data from
                $i = 0;
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand1 WHERE description LIKE '%oven%' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM brand2 WHERE description LIKE '%oven%' LIMIT $start, $per_page") ;
                $dyn_table = '<table border ="1" cellpadding ="10">';

                //create a variable to store the data in
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        //Variables to store vendors information, product number and image as retrieved from the database
                        $brand = $row["Brand"];
                        $model_number = $row["Model Number"];
                        $product_image = $row["Image"];

                        //Set up a loop that puts the information into a grid rather than a single line
                        if($i%4==0) //First number sets the column number
                            {
                                // Starts to draw the table. Adds the vendor name, the product number then breaks line to draw the image underneath the titles
                                $dyn_table .= '<tr><td>' .  $brand . " " . $model_number . '<br>' . $product_image .'</td>';
                            }   
                        else
                            {
                                //This line does the same thing, but once the first if condition hits 4, it jumps to this line to contine drawing.
                                $dyn_table .= '<td>' . $brand . " " . $model_number . '<br>' . $product_image . '</td>';
                            }
                        //Simply adds 1
                        $i++;
                    }
                    //Adds the ending of the table
                    $dyn_table .= '</tr></table>';

                    //Draws the table
                    echo $dyn_table;

                    //Set the pagination links at the bottom of the page
                    if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages)
                        {
                            for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++)
                                {
                                    echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href ="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href ="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                                }
                        }
            ?>
```

And the AJAX (Which I just grabbed off an example from W3

```
  <script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/site/products/ovens/products.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code you've written to handle the problem, it's going to be difficult to give you a concrete recommendation.

Comment: Sory, slipped my mind. I've added the php in.

Comment: Having trouble formatting the AJAX part.

Comment: Fixed that for you.  You have to have a blank line at the beginning and end of a code block.  Also, if by "W3" you mean w3schools, please be aware that their stuff is *horribly* out of date and full of bad practices and security holes.  You probably want to use a modern Javascript library to deal with that stuff instead.  jQuery is the go-to tool around here.

Comment: Also, here, have my usual copypasta, as if you don't already have enough to think about: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Oh boy. Alright, thanks for the information Charles. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, I assume you have something like `page1.php`, `page2.php`...?

Make a `page.php`, read `$_GET['page']` to see which page you should be doing, and in HTML link to `page.php?page=2` and similar.

As Charles says, that's as much as I can offer with the level of detail you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here, have a big fat boring answer.

Your code is *fine*, outside of the whole taint from the `mysql_` family and that prehistoric manual ajax stuff.  Your pagination methodology is solid and follows the usual pattern of finding out how many pages you could possibly have, then grabbing the current page of results based on that limit.  You have all the correct validation bits and pieces there as well.

You're right in that this is a tad inefficient, but unless you have a convenient place to stick a pre-calculated maximum result count / maximum page count, there are very few ways around it.  You may well already have one.  Examine your database structure carefully.  You should also make sure you have appropriate indexing.  Time to play with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

The only thing I could recommend might be unrelated.  It looks like you might need to [read up on database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Your table names (brand1, brand2) suggest that you might have two tables that are entirely identical in structure, with the only difference being that they contain data intended for two different "brands."  This could easily be done in a single table, with the addition of the brand as another column.